# Python list variables not getting modified by if-statement clauses

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I am making a game using the [Langton's ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) algorithm. I want the list tiles to update the number to 0 in this case... But it doesn't. Why?

Note: the direction variable is based on a compass (n, e, w, s)

```
posx = 4
posy = 4
direction = 'w'

tiles = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
def posision(posx, posy, tiles, direction):
    if tiles[posx][posy] == 1:
        tiles[posx][posy] = 0
    if tiles[posx][posy] == 0:
        tiles[posx][posy] = 1

    oldTiles = tiles

    if direction == 'n':
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 1:
            posx = posx+1
            return 'w', tiles
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 0:
            posx = posx-1
            return 'e', tiles
    if direction == 's':
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 0:
            posx = posx+1
            return 'w', tiles
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 1:
            posx = posx-1
            return 'e', tiles
    if direction == 'e':
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 1:
            posy = posy +1
            return 'n', tiles
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 0:
            posy = posy -1
            return 's', tiles
    if direction == 'w':
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 0:
            posy = posy +1
            return 'n', tiles
        if oldTiles[posx][posy] == 1:
            posy = posy -1
            return 's', tiles

direction, tiles = posision(posx, posy, tiles, direction)
print(tiles)
```

Comment: By the way, I'd recommend creating `tiles` with a list comprehension: `tiles = [[1 for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]`.

Comment: There's no need for the function to return `direction` as well as `tiles`.  Also, if you make this a class then you don't need to pass tiles around at all, just refer to it as a data member called `self.tiles`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ON this line:

```
if tiles[posx][posy] == 1:
        tiles[posx][posy] = 0
    if tiles[posx][posy] == 0:
        tiles[posx][posy] = 1
```

You are saying:

```
IF some_var IS 1
    change it to 0  # I've changed it to 0 already
   IF some_var IS 0 # BUt now I am changing back to 1?
     change it to 1
```

I am not sure if this is your correct logic for the game? You probably should change it to:

```
if tiles[posx][posy] == 1:
        tiles[posx][posy] = 0
elif tiles[posx][posy] == 0:  # An else-if condition
        tiles[posx][posy] = 1
```

I also recommend you revisit your flow control logics i.e. all the IF-ELSE ones to see if my explaination makes sense to you. IF-ELSE sphagetti is one of the common problems which is made by even experts sometimes. But as soon as you figure it out, it's okay.

An obvious one is the `oldTiles` modification inside the IF block further down the code.

Comment: Yes, it is going to change the variable from 1 to 0, and 0 to 1.

Comment: When an lets say an ant, walks on a tile with the tag 1 it will walk to the tile to the right of it, and change the tile it stood on to the opposite, if it walks on a tile with the tag 0, it will go to the tile to the left, and change the tile to the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all the `if` statements, try:

```
the_tiles[posx][posy] ^= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement in your position function sets `tiles[posx][posy]` to 0. The next if statement right underneath sets it back to 1. Replace the second by an else statement:

```
if the_tiles[posx][posy] == 1:
    the_tiles[posx][posy] = 0
else:
    the_tiles[posx][posy] = 1
```

Comment: Better yet, avoid the `if`s entirely and do `the_tiles[posx][posy] ^= 1`

Comment: @kindall please post that as an answer. I was about to say the same.